# Giving read/write access to user for mounted android device (MTP)

Tags: debian, mtp

When I mount my android device (using jmtpfs) in /media/android, I don't have access with regular user. I need to switch to root user (using su), and only then can I access /media/android/ folder. How can I enable my regular user to do this?

Comment: `jmptfs` is a FUSE based filesystem. You can set UID/GID/mode and `allow_others` while mounting filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /media with `cd /media`, and then with `ls -l` you can see which user is the owner of your /media/android folder.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       11 Jan  7 20:02 aa
drwxr-xr-x 6 mohammad mohammad 4096 Jan  7 20:03 dev
-rw-r--r-- 1 mohammad mohammad   21 Jan  6 22:19 uAp
```

For example, This is the output of `ls -l` in one of my directories, as you can see the owner of the first file is root but the other two files are me.

You can simply change it with `sudo chown mohammad /media/android`, mohammad is my username you replace it with yours. And also you can change the group too, like this: `sudo chown mohammad:mohammad /media/android`

Comment: It doesn't work, I change the ownership of the android folder, but when I mount my phone it again can't be accessed. When I unmount the phone, I'm reverted to android foldder owner.

Comment: @FedjaMladenovic You should change the ownership after mounting your phone on that folder.

Comment: That doesn't work really. Access is denied